# Save game statistic in simple method?

Tags: unity

I wrote a script to save and load game statistic. It works fine. In this script, two levels have it own score and timer. So, I have to write level by level it own score and timer. The issue is if I have 100 or 200 levels in my game. I have to write for every level. Yes will work, but will take time. So, I was thinking if there any simple method to shift the number of lines like use List or anything else ?

```
public gameStatic dr;

void Awake()    {
    Load_game_end();
}


   public void Save_game_end()  {
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream data_file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/WarWorld.datt");

    level_static data = new level_static();
    data.level1tv = dr.level1t; // level one
    data.level2tv = dr.level2t; // level two
    //
    data.timer1 = dr.finalTime1; // level one
    data.timer2 = dr.finalTime2; // level two
    //
    data.total_money = dr.total_money;


    bf.Serialize(data_file, data);
    data_file.Close();

    Debug.Log("Game full saved");

}

public void Load_game_end() {
    if (File.Exists (Application.persistentDataPath + "/WarWorld.datt"))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream data_file = File.Open (Application.persistentDataPath + "/ballworlds.datt", FileMode.Open);
        level_static data = (level_static)bf.Deserialize(data_file);
        data_file.Close();

        dr.level1t= data.level1tv;
        dr.level2t = data.level2tv;
        //
        dr.finalTime1 = data.timer1;
        dr.finalTime2 = data.timer2;
        //
        dr.total_money = data.total_money;

        Debug.Log("Game full loaded");
    }

    else {
        Debug.Log("save not found");
    }

}

public void delete_save_file() {
    File.Delete(Application.persistentDataPath +"/WarWorld.datt");
    Debug.Log("delete save file");

}

[Serializable]
class level_static
{
    public float total_money; 
    //
    public float level1tv; // height score level 1
    public float level2tv;

    //
    public float timer1; //  level 1 timer
    public float timer2;


}
```

Comment: Using a list sounds like a great idea. How have you tried putting that idea into practice?

Comment: I was think in something like [this](https://hastebin.com/canojujoto.cs). Than, I have to use For function to count how many levels in the list. So, now I have to select first level....I lost. Do you have any clue for me ?

Answer (score 2):

```
   public void Save_game_end()  {
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream data_file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/WarWorld.datt");

    level_static data = new level_static();
    data.level1tv = dr.level1t; // level one
    data.level2tv = dr.level2t; // level two
    //
    data.timer1 = dr.finalTime1; // level one
    data.timer2 = dr.finalTime2; // level two
    //
    data.total_money = dr.total_money;


    bf.Serialize(data_file, data);
    data_file.Close();

    Debug.Log("Game full saved");

}
```

instead of that maybe exclude data.level to params?

```
...Save_game_end(level, finalTime){
```

and for class level_static create custom constructor to set level, timer, money. Use collection to save all levels and timers.

**Example:**

```
   public gameStatic dr;

public List<level_static>  levelStaticList;

void Awake()
{
    Load_game_end();
}


public void Save_game_end()
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream data_file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/WarWorld.datt");

    bf.Serialize(data_file, levelStaticList);
    data_file.Close();

    Debug.Log("Game full saved");
}

public void Load_game_end()
{
    if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/WarWorld.datt"))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream data_file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/ballworlds.datt", FileMode.Open);
        List<level_static> data = (List<level_static>)bf.Deserialize(data_file);
        data_file.Close();

        //if you cant return list from file then try something different (deserialize one by one in the foreach for an example and add to list).

        levelStaticList = data;

        Debug.Log("Game full loaded");
    }

    else
    {
        Debug.Log("save not found");
    }

}

public void delete_save_file()
{
    File.Delete(Application.persistentDataPath + "/WarWorld.datt");
    Debug.Log("delete save file");

}

[Serializable]
class level_static
{
    public level_static(float level, float timer, float money)
    {
        this.level = level;
        this.timer = timer;
        total_money = money;
    }

    public float total_money;
    //
    public float level;

    //
    public float timer;
}
```

Comment: This is new. Maybe you right. but I don't know set it in load. Could you write it please.

Comment: Something like [that](https://hastebin.com/iyaqalabuj.cs)

Comment: Great. Thank you man for the script. I will try it.